# About bound of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$

Can anyone please tell me bound for following series
I simplified this upto

$$(2n-1)-2\left( \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{2}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{n-1}{2n-1} \right)$$

Also I get one of my bound as $\frac{n(n-1)}{2(n+1)}$, 
but this bound is not so good for large values of $n$, so I want to know one largest upper bound and greatest lower bound so that it satisfies for all $n$ as well.

Comment: Upper bound or lower bound ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: I can't get one of them also which is accurate for large n also

Comment: Oh, and another thing. Don't give comments that are actually part of your question. Everything related to the question (like what you simplified the expression upto) should be part of the main body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard integral bounds,$$\int_1^n \frac{n-t}{n+t}dt\le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n+k}\le \int_0^{n-1} \frac{n-t}{n+t}dt$$

Hence $$1+2n\log\left(\frac{2n}{1+n} \right)\le n+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n+k}\le 1+2n\log\left( \frac{2n-1}{n}\right) $$

This is a sharp bound, which also yields asymptotics for the sum a stake:$$n+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n+k}\sim \log(4)n$$

Comment: what is that last statement mean log(4)n

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis

Comment: why then 4 is in bracket like this(4)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm and $\log(4)n = 2\log(2)\cdot n$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n+k}=n\left(H_{2n-1}-H_{n}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k+n-n}{n+k}
 $$ $$ =n\left(2\left(H_{2n-1}-H_{n}\right)-1\right)+1
 $$ where $H_{m}$ is the $m$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). Using the well know bounds for the harmonic number you can find a good approximation for your sum. For example you could use $$\frac{1}{24\left(n+1\right)^{2}}<H_{n}-\log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\gamma<\frac{1}{24n^{2}}.$$ So a lower bound  is $$2n\left(\log\left(\frac{4n-2}{2n+1}\right)-\frac{1}{32n^{2}}\right)-1<n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n+k}$$ and an upper bound is $$n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n+k}<2n\left(\log\left(\frac{4n-2}{2n+1}\right)-\frac{n\left(n-2\right)}{8\left(2n-1\right)^{2}\left(n+1\right)^{2}}\right)-1.$$